# How to add event in Android calendar, repeated every 3 days?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to add an event to the Android calendar using this code:

```
cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DURATION, "P3600S");
values.put(Events.TITLE, "MyTestNew");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "India");
values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1);
values.put(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;BYDAY=SA");
uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

But I want to add this event which should repeat every three days than what will be changed in my `(Events.RRULE,` parameter. How might I do this?

Comment: All about [Calendar content provider](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/).

Comment: let me clarify - you want the event to go like this: monday, thursday, sunday, wednesday,... is that right?

Comment: yes @ Josephus Villarey exactly, and ahead Saturday,tuesday........

Comment: have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871921/add-weekly-event-to-calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I found the solution.

```
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DURATION, "P1800S");
values.put(Events.TITLE, "MyTestNew");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "India");
values.put(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=3");
uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: How to add weekly repeating events to android native calendar, like Event for every Fridays only

Comment: what is this "P1800S"

Comment: @ranjith: See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt - section 4.3.6 "Duration":
`P` is some sort of a divider, `1800` are 1800 seconds, `S` is the unit of time, here `seconds`.

Comment: After running this code, will i be able to see an event in Google Calendar App ??

Answer (score 0):

```
This code start the default calender of android and you can add event on it.

String dtStart = "2012" + "" + "06-11-01T10:50:00Z";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
try {Date date = format.parse(dtStart);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
//cal.setTime(date);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);                                        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");                     
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());                            
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);                           
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1");                         
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);                     
intent.putExtra("title", "Booking Confirm Notification");                           
intent.putExtra("Description", "Please check details");                         
startActivity(intent);


Arun chandravanshi
Thanks.
```

Comment: Thanks Arun But I want add event without open calender.